# Keras 2.2: can't load pre-made model with imagenet weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got a block of code that *used to* work in older versions of Keras, but in Keras 2.2, I get an error about loading a model with not enough layers into a larger model:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D,  Conv2D
from keras.applications import Xception
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Add
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU

kernel_size = (3, 3)  
pool_size = (2, 2)  
nfilters = 3
inputs = Input(shape=(331, 331, 1))
x = inputs
x = Conv2D(nfilters, kernel_size, strides=(1,1), padding='same', use_bias=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)
x =  Add()([x,AveragePooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(inputs)])  # residual skip connection on shrunk image
base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=x)
```

The error I get is on the line with Xception:

`ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 80 layers into a model with 82 layers.`

Here's a link to a [Google Colab notebook that reproduces this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LxgH7ejFfp3wgghBJFXQa0w9xA4T6M7q).

The problem occurs in regard to loading the imagenet weights; if I set weights to `None` there's no problem.

This kind of error can be avoided in a `load_model()` call by passing `by_name=True`, but these premade models like Xception don't allow the `by_name` keyword.

Can anyone explain how to get my code working again under Keras 2.2?

I suppose I could define Xception twice, once by itself with imagenet weights, and the other in my full model with weights=None, and then copy the weights from the former to the latter...but I'd rather not have to do that if possible.

(*"Why are you putting those layers before Xception?"* It's because I'm shrinking a larger image down to the size that Xception requires for its imagnet weights, and to convert my greyscale images to 3-channel images.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error (I get a different one). Can you include the value of `myXshape`?

Comment: @sdcbr Sure. I added the dimensions, and the imports, and a link to a Colab notebook that reproduces my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not complete sure how to explain your error, but you can make it work by treating the Xception model as a layer, calling it on your previous layers and wrapping the entire stack in a model instance. I verified the following in your colab notebook.

```
import keras
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D,  Conv2D
from keras.applications import Xception
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, Add
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU

kernel_size = (3, 3)  
pool_size = (2, 2)  
nfilters = 3
inputs = Input(shape=(331, 331, 1))
x = inputs
x = Conv2D(nfilters, kernel_size, strides=(1,1), padding='same', use_bias=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)
x =  Add()([x,AveragePooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(inputs)])  # residual skip connection on shrunk image

# Xception architecture is just another layer
base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
output = base_model(x)
# Wrap everything into a model
combined_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
```

This will give you a model that looks as follows:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 331, 331, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 331, 331, 3)  27          input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 331, 331, 3)  12          conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 331, 331, 3)  0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 165, 165, 3)  0           leaky_re_lu_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_2 (AveragePoo (None, 165, 165, 1)  0           input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_14 (Add)                    (None, 165, 165, 3)  0           max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
                                                                 average_pooling2d_2[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
xception (Model)                multiple             20861480    add_14[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 20,861,519
Trainable params: 20,806,985
Non-trainable params: 54,534
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Excellent!  You have solved my problem!  Thank you very much!